# client-side javascript execution model

Tags: javascript, browser, virtual-machine

How many javascript virtual machine instances will be created by the browser? Does it create instances on a per-page basis? Or does it use only one instance across different pages?

Comment: It varies per browser, I believe.

Comment: Although, a script in one page affecting another script from a whole different tab...that'd seem to run counter to everything they're trying to do securitywise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It varies per browser, I believe. – GregL Feb 15 at 7:26

Although, a script in one page affecting another script from a whole different tab...that'd seem to run counter to everything they're trying to do securitywise. – cHao Feb 15 at 7:28

This is very much implementation-dependent. Read documentation of individual implementation would help.